# AngularJS : How do you access a directives scope from the same directives controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<authorname skim="skim"></authorname>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('authorname', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { 
        skim: '=skim' 
      },
      controller: function($scope, User) {
        // console.log('skim.author: ', skim.author); doesn't work
        // console.log('$scope.skim.author: ', $scope.skim.author); doesn't work
        // console.log('$scope.skim: ', $scope.skim); undefined
        User.get({ _id: skim.author }, function(user) {
          $scope.author = user.name;
        });
      },
      template: '<small>Skim by {{author}}</small>' // but can access {{skim.author}} here
    };
  });
```

I can access `skim.author` in the template, but not in the controller (which is where I need it). How can I access it in the controller?

Comment: `$scope.skim.author` thats how you do it

Comment: `skim` is exposed on the scope. You access it as `$scope.skim`. Read this for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: oh ok. if people answer questions in the comments instead of as an official answer, does that mean I should delete the question?

Comment: better you delete this question

Comment: @NewDev @HarishR - sorry to reopen this but `$scope.skim.author` inside the controller isn't working. I read through docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive but don't see anything that addresses this.

Comment: @AdamZerner Is the value of `skim` assigned asyncronously from the parent controller?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the question unless it's truly necessary, e.g., flagged, downvoted to oblivion, etc. Even if someone answers in the comments, you can answer your own question with those comments so there's an accepted, working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are setting skim object asynchronously from the parent controller, possibly from another ajax call. But your directive would have instantiated already (controller runs/instantiated first and then the link function). So when you try to access `$scope.skim` it doesn't exist yet. Binding in the template works because they are updated by angular during a digest cycle the happened after the assignment of value to `skim` from the parent controller. So one way you could do is to create a temporary watcher till you get the `skim` two way bound value populated.

```
.directive('authorname', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { 
        skim: '=skim' 
      },
      controller: function($scope, User) {

       /*Create a temporary watch till you get skim or 
         watch skim.author according to how you are assigning*/

        var unWatch = $scope.$watch('skim', function(val){ 

           if(angular.isDefined(val)) { //Once you get skim
              unWatch(); //De-register the watcher
              init(); //Initialize
           }

        });

        function init(){
           User.get({ _id: skim.author }, function(user) {
             $scope.author = user.name;
           });
        }

      },
      template: '<small>Skim by {{author}}</small>' // but can access {{skim.author}} here
    };
  });
```

Comment: You're right, `skim` was being set asynchronously in the parent controller as a result of an ajax call. And your explanation and solution were both perfect. Thanks!